# Should I avoid using Java 7 for the time being because it's so new?

Tags: java, deployment

At the moment my application is coded for 1.6, but there are a few new features in Java 7 that I would like to use (such as **`Files`** and **`NIO`**). Should I avoid using these features or should every client update to Java 7 in order to run it? Assuming most workstations are still running 1.5 ~ 1.6.

Comment: If most workstations are using 1.5-1.6 and you introduce 1.7 features (that potentially use 1.7 bytecode) then what do you think will happen when they try to run your app?

Comment: Well obviously they'd have to update their JRE first...

Comment: You can have multiple versions installed on the same machine. i.e. you don't have to upgrade application which have not been tested for Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best version to use depends on you.

I wouldn't start developing Java 7 until you know the machine which will be running it can have Java 7 installed.

You can either upgrade now, or soon because Java 6 is EOL in November this year http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Or you could be like the many people who are still using Java 1.3 and 1.4 happily because it works.

Comment: You mean "organisations using it happily while their developers grumble or drink heavily".

Comment: Unless you like being paid a daily rate, in which case taking longer to do everything is not a bad thing ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey:You know there are such things as deadlines..You can only stall so much..Otherwise I would agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly subjective question , but I'll bite. It depends on who your client is. Are they flexible enough to upgrade?

Generally, you want to satisfy the most people *right now* .. 1.6 probably has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you can "force" your users to upgrade, then do it, there is no significant risk. In fact, it is risky to use 1.5 because there are no public (security) updates for it, and 1.6 will also reach its end of life in November:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html